# jQuery code not working when running on host account

Tags: jquery, json

I have created a website and all the functionalities work on xampp. I have uploaded the website to my hosting account but I'm unable to run some of the jQuery code. I simply want to open a modal up when the user clicks on the edit button. When I change the data type to text the modal opens up but I'm unable to pass the data. Am I supposed to activate something in cPanel?

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
       var product_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"includes/products/fetch.inc.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{product_id:product_id},  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#name').val(data.name);  
                 $('#quantity').val(data.quantity);  
                 $('#barcode').val(data.barcode);   
                 $('#product_id').val(data.id);  
                 $('#insert').val("Update");  
                 $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
            }  
       });  
  });
```

Fetch.inc.php

```
 ?php  

 include("../dbh.inc.php");     
 if(isset($_POST["product_id"]))  
 {  
     $query = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts WHERE id = '".$_POST["product_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
      echo json_encode($row);  
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? How about in the _Network_ tab of the console? Do you see the AJAX request? If so, what is the response?

Comment: Also, what **exactly** is the PHP filename? Is it `fetch.inc.php` or `Fetch.inc.php`?

Comment: It is `fetch.inc.php` I've checked the console and error logs. No errors showing. The network status is 200

Comment: I can display the retrieved data in the console. The only problem is that the modal isn't popping up :/

Comment: So it works locally and you're getting the expected data (ie `console.log(data)` shows an object or array) on the remote host and you're absolutely sure there's no error messages both before and after you click on edit button?

Comment: It could be the response isn't valid JSON (for some reason) when you have `dataType: 'json'`. Add an error handler to your `$.ajax` call, eg `error: function(_, status, err) { console.error(status, err) }`

Comment: I found the problem.  I had written some code to check if i connected to the database successfully in the `dbh.inc.php` file. I guess it was conflicting when fetching data from the table. Thanks for your help Phil.

Answer (score -1):

The connection check in the database connection file was conflicting when fetching data from the tables.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "inv";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

//The echo code conflicts while fetching data from database as it prints out extra data.
if(!$connect){
    echo "Could not connect";
}else{
    echo "Connected";
}
```